# Wordpress Image galleries not loading on certain browsers and devices

Tags: wordpress, safari

I've been asked to take a look at a website where the image galleries are not displaying correctly. I've found that there's differing results depending on browser and platform. For this example, I'm looking at three Apple devices, all using Safari. I cannot, nor can the client, see the image galleries in Safari, but I can in Firefox - [Gallery page](http://fincadelalamo.com/gallery/)

These seem to be built into the theme, rather than managed by a plugin. However, I did put Envira Gallery on and am having similar results.

I've tried turning off all the plugins and systematically turning them back on, that has no effect.

The website is running a theme called [The 7.2](http://dream-theme.com/), which is up to date. Wordpress is also up to date.

The site does have a PHP upgrade warning [Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkJJf.png), but I don't currently have access to the client's control panel to upgrade it.

Any ideas gratefully received

Pictures: [MacBook Pro Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAHn6.jpg), [iPad Pro Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrWOx.jpg), [iPad mini 5 Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wz5fG.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that it is setting opacity to 0

[image]

Soon as I take that off it shows/works fine.

Comment: Thanks! I had to trawl through some minified css and caches to find that one and get it clear of the site - nice work!